# PyQt Scaling background image using styleSheet ? or any other way?

Tags: background, size, pyqt, stylesheet

I'm trying to resize a background image on a button

```
btn.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/AddButton.png);"
                         "background-repeat: no-repeat;");
```

tried it with

```
background-size: 10px auto;
```

but pyqt seems to be missing this CSS attribute

Is there any other way of scaling the background image on the button?
I need the background image as the icon on the button will be used on top.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use border-image. Since the border-image property provides an alternate background, it is not required to specify a background-image when border-image is specified. In the case when both of them are specified, the border-image draws over the background-image.